# Laravel, How to use ajax without having to duplicate data

Tags: php, laravel

Im new to laravel, and i encountered a problem.

```
public function index($type = null)
{
    $items = $this->best();
    if (Request::ajax())
        return View::make('item_main', $items) -> with('items',$items);
    else
        $this->layout->content = View::make('main', $items) -> with('items',$items);
}
```

My main.blade.php looks like this:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('sidebar')
    @parent

    <p>This is appended to the master sidebar.</p>
@stop

@section('content')
    @foreach ($items as $item)
        {{$item->myth}}
    @endforeach 
@stop
```

For the ajax, i need to load only

```
@foreach ($items as $item)
    {{$item->myth}}
@endforeach
```

How do i do that without duplicate this part of code??

I tought about loading a view inside of a blade.
That what i did in codeigniter.

Thanks alot!

Comment: Yes, that is what you would do, something like `@include('view.name')`, as [per the docs](http://four.laravel.com/docs/templates#other-blade-control-structures)

Comment: You should put it as an answer. And you may add a notice that you are able to load blade layouts without templates too.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function index($type = null)
    {
        $items = $this->best();
        if (Request::ajax())
            return View::make('item_main') -> with('items',$items);
        else
            $this->layout->content = View::make('main') -> with('items',$items);
    }
```

item_main.blade.php:

```
@foreach ($items as $item)
    {{$item->myth}}
@endforeach
```

main.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('sidebar')
    @parent

    <p>This is appended to the master sidebar.</p>
@stop

@section('content')
    @include('item_main')
@stop
```

Credit goes to  Wrikken.